# '+' character ignored from POST data using c# to webapi2

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I have a client that Connects to Asp.net Webapi2,Using Identity & OAuth2 for Authentication.
In Authentication Process , whenever Password Field Contains '+' character.The Server Just Ignore this Character!!!(And Most Other Sign Chars Mentioned In Test below)

```
string data = "grant_type=password&username=" + username + "&password=" + password;
byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
data.PostToUrl();//This Is just pseudoCode
```

In Server Debug:
**Sent Data : password=test+1

Received Data : password=test 1**

test2
**Sent Data : "+_)(*&^%$#@!~"

Received Data :" _)(*"**

Thanks.

Comment: You have to encode it to '%2b' edit: on phone idk how to do the correct format for code in comments from here since I can't do the characters so ignore the '

Comment: Not just in this case, it is good to encode parameters (posted in request body or sent through querystring).

Comment: As query strings might end up in logfiles, you might consider moving the username and password to the post data instead to keep them secure. That will fix your encoding issue too.

Comment: Data Is Sent With POST method, as mentioned in title

Comment: It's the same, except for that the data is not stored in the url, it's store in the content body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the issue?  With HTTP URL a `+` is equivalent to a space.  In fact `%20` can also be used.

When sending data in a query always use [UrlEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode(v=vs.110).aspx); as in

```
var q = string.Format("grant_type=password&username={0}&password={1}", 
    HttpUtility.UrlEncode(username),
    HttpUtility.UrlEncode(password));
```

Comment: I use POST, Why shoud I care about HTTP URL?

Comment: You haven't shown the POST code.  But I suspect the `Content-Type` is `application-x-www-form-urlencoded`, so you must follow the rules.

Comment: Yes It is,Thanks I got it.

Comment: What About Content-Type:application/json ? no need to URLEncode?

Comment: No, but you would have to encode as JSON and does the service accept JSON?  Also JSON expects UTF-8 by default.

Answer (score 2):

[HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w(VS.80).aspx)

this will help solve the problem with special characters such as + anad #

To use it you'll need to add a reference to System.Web (Project Explorer > References > Add reference > System.Web)

Once you've done that you can use it to encode any items you wish